# Modify value of a deep key in an associative array

Tags: php, arrays

Let's assume we have a simple `$array` like the following.

```
$array = array(
    'a' => array(
        'b' => array(
            'c' => 'd'
        ),
        'e' => 'f'
    ),
    'g' => 'h'
);
```

Given an **arbitrary** array of `$keys = array('a', 'b', 'c')` and a value `$value = 'i'`, I would like to change value of `$array['a']['b']['c']` to `i`.

For simplicity, let's assume that elements of `$keys` are all valid, i.e. for any positive `j`, `$keys[j]` exists and is a child of `$keys[j - 1]`.

I came up with a solution by passing a reference to the array and looping over keys but my implementation seems a bit ugly. Is there any straight forward way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// current key index (starting at 0)
$i = 0;
// current array (starting with the outermost)
$t = &$array;

// continue until keys are exhausted
while ($i < count($keys) - 1) {

    // update array pointer based on current key
    $t = &$t[$keys[$i++]];
}

// update value at last key
$t[$keys[$i]] = $value;
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0598f00ab719c005a0560c18f91ab00154ba9453

Comment: Shouldn't `$t = &$array` instead?

Comment: Yeah, you are right :) I was just testing it out and you helped be fix my bug.

Comment: Thanks dana. Your latest revision is much better than what I came up with!